# Pass parameters to a function through add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to build a radius based location search, to return relevant posts from various CPT I have. the overall process works, but I have a problem passing some of the parameters to the function in my functions.php file (I get them from the form but don't know how to pass them on to the function).

The parameters are the lat lng and radius (which are currently written manually to the code in my functions.php).

**search.php**

```
<?php
    // Get objects from search form
    if($_GET['spot_name'] && !empty($_GET['spot_name']))
    {
        $spot_name = $_GET['spot_name'];
    }
    if($_GET['spot_type'] && !empty($_GET['spot_type']))
    {
        $spot_type = $_GET['spot_type'];
    }
    if($_GET['lat'] && !empty($_GET['lat']))
    {
        $spot_lat = $_GET['lat'];
    }
    if($_GET['lng'] && !empty($_GET['lng']))
    {
        $spot_lng = $_GET['lng'];
    }
    if($_GET['radius'] && !empty($_GET['radius']))
    {
        $spot_radius = $_GET['radius'];
    }

    // Declare the query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $spot_type,
        'post_title' => $spot_name
    );

    // Add our filter before executing the query
    add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'location_posts_where' );

    // Execute the query
    $location_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Remove the filter just to be sure its
    // not used again by non-related queries
    remove_filter( 'posts_where' , 'location_posts_where' );

    // The Loop
    if ( $location_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $location_query->have_posts() ) {
            $location_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            the_field('mp_spot_loc_lat');
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function location_posts_where( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $lat = '41.834536';
    $lng = '39.2440537479998';

    $radius = 60;

    $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_lat_lng_post WHERE
         ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                        * cos( radians( lat ) )
                        * cos( radians( lng )
                        - radians(" . $lng . ") )
                        + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") )
                        * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")";

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the filter you can just use a custom SQL query using $wpdb and keep all the code in one search.php file.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the steps of applying and removing the filter.

The wpdb filter, only applies itself after the query starts and I have removed it too early. moving it to after the end of the query solved the problem.

now, I can pass my parameters as globals and make the search radius and altitudes dynamic.

```
global $spot_lat;
global $spot_lng;
global $spot_radius;
```